# how to put a regex test inside a arr.find

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
const arr = [{id: "12f"},{id: "12F"},{id: "13"}]
const itemToBeFound = {id: "12f"}
```

I want to be able to find that item using something like `RegExp(/12f/i).test(string)`

So the point of using the regexp is to be case insensitive. I know I could use toLowerCase or toUpperCase, I was just wanting to know how to do it this way.

So `arr.find(({id}) => id == regexp)` something to that affect. I haven't been able to figure out how to achieve this yet.

Comment: So you know how to test a string against a regex, and it’s not `id == regexp`.

Comment: `arr.find( s => JSON.stringify( s ) == JSON.stringify(itemToBeFound) )`

Comment: I think objects are not comparable, so you need to stringify the object. This may be not performance wise, but at least it works: `arr.find((item) => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(itemToBeFound));` *Edit:* just noticed that you want to compare only with an id, not the whole object state. Then, this is not necessary

Comment: All of the answers have it really verbose for some reason. `arr.find(({id}) => /12f/i.test(id))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just test the property against the `RegExp`

```js
const arr = [{
  id: "12f"
}, {
  id: "12F"
}, {
  id: "13"
}];
var regexp = new RegExp(/12f/i);
console.log(arr.find(({id}) => /12f/i.test(id)))
console.log(arr.filter(({id}) => /12f/i.test(id)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to return all the items with that id, I know that was not part of the question. I think find just returns the first element that meets those requirements. Great answer, I can accept in 4 min.

Comment: @TaylorAustin, Then you have to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`. The  `.filter()` method will return an array. updated answer

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner does all the job, according to the current question setup:

`const foundItems = arr.filter((item) => (/[itemToBeFound.id]/gi).test(item.id))`

Answer (score 1):

The `pattern` and `flags` `params` of [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) can be leveraged conduct dynamic comparison like so:

```js
// Loose Match.
const filter = (array, target) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(target.id, 'i')
  return array.filter(x => regex.test(x.id))
}

// Proof.
console.log('12f', filter([{id: "12f"},{id: "12F"},{id: "13"}], {id: "12f"}))
console.log('13', filter([{id: "12f"},{id: "12F"},{id: "13"}], {id: "13"}))
```